# Passing a heap as an argument

Tags: c, arrays, heap

I tried to make several functions which passes a heap as a parameter through the code below. However, it did not turned out to be what I expected it to be.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void upHeap_min2 (int *heap, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    int parentIdx = getParentIdx(index);
    if (heap[index] < heap[parentIdx])
    {
        int temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[parentIdx];
        heap[parentIdx] = temp; 

        upHeap_min2(heap, parentIdx);
    }
}

void pushValue (int *heap, int count, int value)
{
    count++;
    heap[count] = value;
    upHeap_min2(heap, count);   
}

void view(int *heap, int count)
{
    printf("Values inside heap: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int heapDemo[101];
    int count = -1;
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 30);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 20);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 40);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 90);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 10);

    view(heapDemo, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Function to get parent index:

```
int getParentIdx (int index)
{
    return (index-1)/2;
}
```

The code above should have printed

```
10 20 40 90 30
```

But instead it printed nothing. I have also thought to pass it as a double pointer as well but i did not work. Does this mean I cannot pass a heap as a parameter (which means i have to declare the heap as a global variable) or there is another way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious why you do not pass `count` as a pointer on line `pushValue(heapDemo, count, 30);`. Am I missing sth? Wouldn't you need yo pass `count` via pointer, like `pushValue(heapDemo, &count, 30);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pushValue` function takes the `count` argument **by value** (which means the function receives a *copy* of the data), so it is never modified in the `main` function. Instead, you should pass `count` as a pointer, and (thus) will need to dereference it inside the function:

```c
void pushValue(int* heap, int* count, int value)
{
    ++(*count);
    heap[*count] = value;
    upHeap_min2(heap, *count);
}
```

Then, in `main`, you should call it using the *address* of `count`:

```c
    pushValue(heapDemo, &count, 30); // And similarly for the other calls
```

Also, the loop in your `view` function stops one short of the end. Change the loop limit to `i <= count`. (This function *uses* `count` but doesn't *modify* it, so passing by value is OK.):

```c
void view(int* heap, int count)
{
    printf("Values inside heap: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: May  I ask... Why did you use `++(*count)` instead of `(*count)++` ?

Comment: @Brian989 In this case, there's no difference in the outcome. I was just doodling around with the code, made that change (more my style than anything else) and neglected to change it back. One reason I think that the pre-increment is better, though, is if you 'forget' the brackets: Although `++*count` will work, `*count++` will not!

Comment: Thanks for the help @Adrian. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid solution, let me explain

```
#include<stdio.h>

void upHeap_min2 (int *heap, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    int parentIdx = getParentIdx(index);
    if (heap[index] < heap[parentIdx])
    {
        int temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[parentIdx];
        heap[parentIdx] = temp; 

        upHeap_min2(heap, parentIdx);
    }
}
int getParentIdx (int index)
{
    return (index-1)/2;
}

void pushValue (int *heap, int *count, int value)
{
    *count = *count + 1;
    heap[*count] = value;
    upHeap_min2(heap, *count);   
}

void view(int *heap, int *count)
{
    printf("Values inside heap: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= *count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int heapDemo[101];
    int conter = -1; //new var
    int *count = &conter;
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 30);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 20);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 40);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 90);
    pushValue(heapDemo, count, 10);

    view(heapDemo, count);

    return 0;
}
```

The main error is that you were passing counter as simple variable, and you should do it as a pointer, this causes that `counter` never get incremented, so I created a pointer to that variable and now `counter` is incremented and it prints what you expect. In addition I have modified the body of the for you were using to print the values

Comment: This does not explain why passing `count` rather than `&count` did not work. That may be obvious to you, but a person asking about this does not have that knowledge, so an answer should provide it.

Comment: Ok. The fact is that if you pass count, you are passing the variable as value, so it will pass a copy of the variable to the method, and the original variable ```count``` will notnever be increased. If you pass a reference ```&count```, now you are increasing ```count``` variable. Here you can find more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Thanks @Josep! I literally thought that I passed the array improperly.... It worked just like what you said.